# I get undefined error when trying to access iframes in gmail from my chrome extension but not from the developer console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extension (content script) that will add text after the "More" in the top black bar in gmail. Those elements are encapsulated in the `canvas_frame` iframe.

When I try to access those elements with:

`document.getElementById('canvas_frame').contentWindow.document.getElementById('gbz').innerHTML = scr;`

I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined`. But if I type that code directly into the chrome developer console it works. Why is this? How can I access and modify that element from my chrome extension.

I'm new with javascript so I am likely missing something obvious. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
document.getElementById('canvas_frame').contentDocument.document.getElementById('gbz').innerHTML = src;
```

Comment: Make sure an iframe with the id canvas_frame exists on the page

Comment: It does. I'm running this on www.mail.google.com. In fact, this code works if I type it into my chrome dev console, it just doesn't work if it's running from my extension.

Comment: I think it might be caused by [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=20773). Is there any way around it?

Comment: That was from 2009.. so I am not sure if it is relevant now... I would try removing  "sandbox='allow-same-origin allow-scripts'" ... and using the javascript provided above

Comment: I never added "sandbox='allow-same-origin allow-scripts'", where would I remove it from?

Comment: That JS still did not work out. It still gives the same errors as above.

Answer (score 0):

I have built Chrome Extensions myself and have encountered this issued, there are a couple of ways to mitigate it, one is to run a timer loop in JS looking for #canvas_frame and stop it when you find it, the other is to listen for DOM node insert events and again, if the element you are looking for has been inserted, start doing what you want to do.

While canvas_frame has been the "content area" element for Gmail to interact with if that's what you need to do, currently (as of a few days ago) I've encountered instances of Google Apps Gmail that DO NOT have a content_frame, or rather, have one for an instant when the page loads and then it gets removed, I'm not sure what shenanigans Google is pulling, but since they don't provide an official API for making Gmail Chrome Extensions (so very unfortunately), we are at their mercy as Extension developers...